# Slurm job, knowing what node it is on

Tags: bash, slurm

Is there a way in bash/slurm for the script to know which node it is running on?

so I sbatch a bash script called wrapCode.sh, and I am monitoring script time as well as which node it is running on.  I know how to monitor the script time, but is there a way to echo out at the end which node I was on?

sstat does this, but I need to know what my job id is, which the script also doesn't seem to know (or at least I haven't been able to find it).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple, yet effective, and often used, way to write in the job output on which node it ran is to add

```
srun hostname
```

to it. Also the job id is available from within the job script through environment variable SLURM_JOB_ID ; so you can use

```
sstat -j $SLURM_JOB_ID
```

in your slurm script to get the information you want.

Comment: is there a variable that contains the node names. For instance in PBS one can do `cat $PBS_NODEFILE > machinefile` and this would create a `machinefile` with all the nodes names.

Comment: The variable `SLURM_JOB_NODELIST` holds the list of nodes. (not the path to a file that contains the list of nodes)

Comment: thanks. I was experimenting today and figured out that `srun hostname > machinefile` would also create the proper machine file. It would also print multiple lines if more than one process per node is specified.

Answer (score 8):

The jobid for your job can be found in the environment variable SLURM_JOBID.
This variable is automatically set by SLURM upon submission of your job.

As for finding the name of the node running your job, this can be found in the environment variable SLURMD_NODENAME.

The variable SLURM_NODELIST will give you a list of nodes allocated to a job (unless you run a job across multiple nodes, this will only contain one name).

There are lot of variables that contain information on your job, see https://slurm.schedmd.com/sbatch.html#lbAH

Answer (score 3):

When you submit a job to the grid, you always get a message that tells you the JobID.  If you do this interactively, you will see something like this:

```
$ sbatch wrapCode.sh
Submitted batch job 106
```

Therefore, you can write a simple wrapper bash script to do the job submission and get the JobID for you.  After that, you can use the `scontrol` command to get detailed information about the job (including the node) as see below:

```
    #!/bin/bash

    Command="sbatch wrapCode.sh"
    Submit_Output="$($Command 2>&1)"
    JobId=`echo $Submit_Output | grep 'Submitted batch job' | awk '{print $4}'`
    echo $JobId

    # --> Sleep here for a few seconds to wait until the job is actually launched
    Host=`scontrol show job $JobId | grep ' NodeList' | awk -F'=' '{print $2}'`
    echo $Host
```

Answer (score 1):

Knowing the job id from previous answers, you can also use `sacct` in a terminal to get resources allocated to your job, including node names:

```
sacct -j JOB_ID --format=JobID,Start,End,Elapsed,NCPUS,NodeList,NTasks
```