# SLURM: Save job script

Tags: slurm, sbatch

In SLURM, I can easily specify the files for logging in my job script:

```
#SBATCH --output=logs/output-%j
#SBATCH --error=logs/error-%j
```

Now, I use a jobscript that is generated programmatically. Whenever I submit a job, I'd like to save that jobscript as `logs/jobscript-%j`.

**How could I do that?** (The main difficulty seems to be to get `%j`.)

Comment: You might want to take a look at [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43944543/slurm-job-knowing-what-node-it-is-on/) and do something similar within your script.

Answer (score 1):

Within your run, `$SLURM_JOB_ID` gives you the job ID, `%j`.

Answer (score 1):

When you submit the job, Slurm responds with the job ID. So capture that output (newer versions of Slurm make this easier with the option `--parsable`) in a Bash variable and use `mv` to rename the submission script as wanted; e.g.

```
JOBID=$(sbatch --parsable <name of submission script>)
mv <name of submission script> logs/jobscript-$JOBID
```